# In javascript or Jquery, which kind of object have .element property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of code

`var scrollYRelativeTo = $(options.bRelativeScrollY.element ? options.bRelativeScrollY.element : window);`

I can't find what kind of object is expected in `bRelativeScrollY` in order to retrieve the element.

Comment: Are you using any plugin? Wow search `bRelativeScrollY` even google has no answer

Comment: Are you just wanting to scroll a specific element into view?

Comment: It's an object home made over jquery datatable

Comment: I want the height of the Datatable use tue full space of a Dialog

Comment: With the information you've given us it could literally be anything.  I could make an object right now that has those properties with 1 line of script, so it doesn't mean a thing.

Comment: It's obviously a DOM node because if not set, default is window object. So i guess, element should be a scrollable wrapper DOM element

Comment: the function calculate the height of the table relatively to a given object. The object is send in parameter in  `bRelativeScrollY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which kind of objects have .element property

Any custom object with that property, in your case for example `options = {bRelativeScrollY: {element: document.documentElement}}`. Such objects often describe views or widgets which have a reference to their root node in a property named `element`, `el` or `$el`.

Without more information, such as the docs for your code or the surrounding declarations, it's hard to tell.

Comment: {element: document.documentElement} this is what I was missing. thx